# Android: Send HTTP post with multiple values to Web Server

Tags: android

```
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient
I would like to add more ids and stringdatas,

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12348"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "wassup"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

When I try above code, the server only get the last id and stringdata values. How can I send multiple IDs using one HTTP Post Request?

Comment: can you get any solution becuse same thing i requred i had ArrayList of id,stringdata and etc and i want to post this all arralist data in sigle connection

Answer (score 0):

It only gets the last ones as http parameters have to be unique. You could programmatically change the names to id1, id2, etc and then iterate through them server side. Personally in this situation I would send the data as XML.